# Python Email lib message_from_bytes function error

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I'm trying to get emails from my gmail account using python. but whenever I call the **email.message_from_bytes**.
an error is generated.

```py
import imaplib , email, os

def reademail():
    con = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com")
    username = 'xyz@gmail.com'
    password = 'xyz'
    con.login(username, password)

    def get_body(msg):
        if msg.is_multipart():
            return get_body(msg.get_payload(0))
        else:
            return msg.get_payload(None, True)

    con.select('INBOX')
    result, data = con.fetch(b'340', '(RFC822)')
    raw = email.message_from_bytes(data[0][1])
    # print data


    print (get_body(raw))


print reademail()
```

#### Error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "pyt.py", line 25, in <module>
>     print reademail()
>   File "pyt.py", line 18, in reademail
>     raw = email.message_from_bytes(data[0][1])
> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'message_from_bytes'
> ```

Comment: And why do you feel `message_from_bytes()` is a thing?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you are using python 2.7.
Python3 email module has `message_from_bytes` function and python 2.7 does not have it.

`email` module in python 2.7 has two functions `message_from_file` and `message_from_string`. Probably one of them should work.

Comment: So what do I use for Python 2.7?

Comment: You should use either message_from_file or message_from_string

Comment: @YuriGinsburg, you really should edit your answer, not leave comments with more information.

Comment: @StephenRauch My answer to original question was about the cause of error.
And the additional question was asked in the comment, so I have answered to it in the comment also.

Comment: @YuriGinsburg, kinda missing the point here.  If you look carefully, there is in fact no actual question, in the question. So... what is really being asked is: *how do I fix my code?*  The answer should answer the question.  Comments, not so much.

Comment: @StephenRauch Excuse me, but I was answering the question explicitly asked in the comment. "So what do I use for Python 2.7?"

Comment: @YuriGinsburg, my bad, you are right, sorry I bothered you.

Comment: @YuriGinsburg kindly edit your answer so I can accept it.
message_from_string works

Answer (score 0):

Here’s an example of how you might use [message_from_bytes()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.parser.html#email.message_from_bytes) at an interactive Python prompt:

```
>>> import email
>>> msg = email.message_from_bytes(myBytes)
```

Comment: How does this fix things?

Comment: Does not help at all.